# How to change the major and minor values for ibeacon without using vendor's SDK

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, altbeacon

I am experimenting with my Kontakt ibeacons using altBeacon lib for Android. My app detects the beacons with their default UUID, Major and Minor values provided by the company. I want to change the Major and Minor of each beacon to represent a hierarchy of my indoor features. Is it possible to achieve that without using Kontakt's SDK? In that case how?

Suggesstions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

iBeacon, as a standard, was designed with one-way communication in mind. It's broadcast-only. Apple's Core Location, on top of which iBeacon was built, does not expose any methods for connecting directly to an iBeacon device and changing its identifiers (UUID, Major, Minor).

It's beacon vendors that enable beacon connectivity and ajdusting IDs and settings on beacons, as part of their respective stacks. That's why you need to use your vendor's SDK to change the identifiers. Many of them, however, have released apps based on their own SDKs to make it simpler (e.g. we at Estimote, Radius, Gimbal).

Cheers.